# How would you translate 佛系 into English?

Tags: translation

Wikipedia ([https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/佛系](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%9B%E7%B3%BB)) says:

> 佛系是中文網路新生的流行語，約在2018年左右開始比較頻繁的在中文網路跟媒體出現，在中文的語境裡大致意思是指怎麼都行、看淡一切、無欲無求的一種生活態度。[1]該詞據考證來源於2014年日本的《non-no》[2]，提出所謂的「佛男子」（日语：仏男子）的概念，是指专注于自己的兴趣或工作，不愿花时间与异性交往的男子。[3]

Google Translation:

> Buddhism is a buzzword for Chinese Internet new students. It appeared more frequently in Chinese Internet and media around 2018. In the Chinese context, it roughly means anything that can do anything, look down on everything, and have no desires. Attitude to life. [1] The term is based on research from Japan’s "non-no" [2] in 2014. It puts forward the concept of the so-called "Buddha Man" (Japanese: 仏男), which means to focus on one's own interests or work, and not willing to Men who spend time with the opposite sex. [3]

How would you translate 佛系 into English?

Comment: 个人感觉佛系这个词并不好，佛门的人都说了，佛教里的无为也不是什么都不干。个人感觉还不如说"看淡一切"，regard everything as unimportant.

Comment: 佛系 can be translated to "low-energy" in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Buddha-like youngsters/youth" is a loyal translation which has found widespread use in the news. "Buddhist youth" is also found, but without context people may take it literally as youths of the Buddhist religion, which is unideal. I believe you may want to consider the above if translating `佛系青年` as a set phrase.
2. You may consider adjectives such as "unambitious", "reclusive", or "indoorsy" (informal) if translating `佛系` alone. Personally, I find "que-será-será" (or "whatever-will-be-will-be"; hyphenation is required, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier)) captures the nuance of `佛系` best. However, unlike "Buddha-like", these adjectives are only explanatory and thus heavily context-dependent.
3. Some proposed adjectives such as "tranquil" or "geeky" are in my opinion inaccurate.

References:

- http://en.people.cn/n3/2017/1214/c90000-9304484.html
- https://www.scmp.com/magazines/style/news-trends/article/2166781/are-chinas-affluent-buddha-youth-turning-their-backs
- https://www.cityu.edu.hk/edge/grant/tdg/projects/projects_abstract/6000696.pdf
- https://kknews.cc/essay/meplla9.html

Comment: "Que-será-será" is good. Also from popular culture. Recent enough. Accurate.

Answer (score 0):

佛系： Buddha style

佛系男孩：Buddha style boy (apparently originally from Japan)

Answer (score 0):

**Zen**

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%9B%E7%B3%BB)

> **佛系**
> (slang, neologism, of a person) carefree, calm and easygoing
>
> 1. (supposedly resembling a practitioner of Zen Buddhism); zen; chill
>    佛系青年  ―  fóxì qīngnián  ―  zen youth (slang)